# Cannot locate MessageFactory in SmsSender example

Tags: twilio

The SmsSender example (Java) refers to a Account.getMessageFactory() API that I can't seem to locate. There is a SmsFactory that should be used instead?

I am using twilio-java-sdk 3.3.15.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Twilio Developer Evangelist here.

`twilio-java-sdk-3.3.15` was released about 8 months ago (about March or April 2013) when Twilio were still using the `SMS` resource. In September 2013 Twilio [rolled out the `Messages` resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message) as we started support MMS messaging, and [deprecated the `SMS` resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sms).

The examples and sample code on the website has been updated to reflect this.

while you could use `SmsFactory`, you should really upgrade to `twilio-java-sdk-3.4.1` ([see release history on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java/releases)) and use `MessageFactory`.

You can download the [latest Java helper library from Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, thanks, it works ! I believe this doc needs an update then : https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/devenvironment

Comment: Indeed it does. Can you email me on wawra at twilio dot com, I'd love to send you a thank you for spotting that.